# how to pass value from firstviewcontroller to thirdview controller in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have declared a string in firstviewcontroller str1 and i want to get that string in thirdview controller and use it inside if loop.

**firstviewcontroller**

```
 SecondViewController *secondview=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
secondview.str1=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];
```

**thirdviewcontroller**

```
if([str1 isEqualToString:@"X"])
   //&&[str12 isEqualToString:@"hospital"])
```

but it doesnt seem to work.pls help to sort out

Comment: You're showing how second controller gets created but how do you go to the third?

Comment: you are setting the str and pushing the secondviewcontroller not the thirdviewcontroller

Comment: yes.i want to get string in firstview to thirdview

Comment: why you are not allocating the secondviewcontroller with xib?

Comment: also check the variable in viewDidAppear of thirdView if that is UI property

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SecondViewController *secondview=[[SecondViewController alloc]]nitWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondView.str1 = @"testString";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `prepareForSegue` method, you can set a @property on each of your view controllers. You'll need to either use storyboard IDs or set your view controllers up as strong @properties.

VC1:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (_secondView && _secondView.yourPropertyName)
        _secondView.yourPropertyName = @"something";
}
```

VC2:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (_thirdView && _thirdView.yourPropertyName)
        _thirdView.yourPropertyName = self.yourPropertyName;
}
```